# TypeError on target.dispatchEvent when console.log variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to run tests on my `react` components but I am getting this error when I `console.log(nav)`

error:

```
Chrome 44.0.2403 (Mac OS X 10.10.4) App has nav FAILED
    Error: the error "TypeError: target.dispatchEvent is not a function" was thrown, throw an Error :)
```

code:

```
import React from 'react/addons';
var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;
import testHelper from '../../test/helpers/testHelper.js';
import App from '../../app/views/app.js';
var app = testHelper.getRouterComponent(App);

describe('App', function() {
    it('has nav', function(done) {
        var nav = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(app, 'nav');
        console.log(nav);
        expect(nav).to.exist;
        done();
    });
});
```

Not quite sure how to debug this or why this is occurring. When I removed the `console.log(nav)` the error does not appear.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of `console.log` try :

```
console.log(require('util').inspect(nav, { depth: null }));
```

Comment: I had a very similar issue and this solved it (Difference is, I was using `TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag`)